# Android: how to mix rectangle and circle in Drawable?

Tags: android, drawable

I would like to set my TextView background like that (the blue part):

[image]

Is it possible to do that with just a drawable XML?

Thanks guys!

Comment: if you want your `Drawable` to have ***any size***, the answer is NO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to mix it up.. 
you can directly use.. 
rectangle shape with rounded corner as below.

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
     <corners
          android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
          android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

     <solid android:color="#007EE1" />

     <padding
          android:bottom="3dp"
          android:left="3dp"
          android:right="3dp"
          android:top="3dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!